# HTACCESS how to mod_rewrite the website Asset File paths?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With `Apache`, how to make a URL (lets say an Image Path) to be actually coming from another location. For example, i have a `html` page with an URL like:

apple.html, with the original codes inside:

```
<img src="http://www.myoldsite.com/assets/image/apple.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.myoldsite.com/assets/image/orange.jpg" />
```

But actually i want this path to be re-written to:

```
<img src="http://www.mynewsite.com/image/apple.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.mynewsite.com/image/orange.jpg" />
```

So when i access the `apple.html` page, the image should be coming from new location, without needed to go and change the actual codes inside the files each.

But actually i'm totally weak in `.htaccess` rules. When i used like following, it is showing error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http://www.mynewsite.com/image/(.*) /assets/image/$1 [QSA, L]
```

I am having thousands of pages like this but I am totally stuck with `.htaccess` rules.
What am i missing please? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that both domains point to the same apache instance?

You seem to have switched the arguments for the `RewriteRule`. The syntax is:

```
RewriteRule UrlsMatchingThis ChangeToThis [params]
```

So in your case I would do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/assets/image/(.*) http://www.mynewsite.com/image/$1  [R,NC,L]
```

This matches all requests where the part just after the tld is /assets/image/(anything).
The flags I have used is

```
R redirect
NC Ignore case
L Last rewrite rule for this request
```

You may want to add a condition to the `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^(www\.)?myoldsite\.com$                [NC]
RewriteRule ^/assets/image/(.*) http://www.mynewsite.com/image/$1  [R,NC,L]
```

This will only rewrite your requests if the domain is myoldsite.com, with or without `www`.

Se http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for documentation of the rewrite module.

Comment: Hi unfortunately NO. The domains are ofcourse on the Different Servers. Not same. So will your answer still work?

Comment: Yes.. but it needs to be on the old server. The requests will enter the old server as it always has, and the apache there will redirect to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(image/.+)$ /assets/$1 [NC,L]
```